# How to mint ERC20 with it's address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain, pancakeswap

i am going through [PancakeSwap docs](https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/migration/masterchef-v2#testnet-environment) and trying to use it on test net.I am trying to use dummy tokens but thi section i dont't uderstand:

```
$CAKE: 0xFa60D973F7642B748046464e165A65B7323b0DEE
(mintable by using mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) public)
$BUSD: 0x8516Fc284AEEaa0374E66037BD2309349FF728eA
(mintable by using mint(uint256 amount) public)
$WBNB: 0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd
```

but how to do this `(mintable by using mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) public)` or `(mintable by using mint(uint256 amount) public)` ?

I found something like this:

```
   pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.6.0/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyCakeToken is ERC20, Ownable {


address CAKE = 0xFa60D973F7642B748046464e165A65B7323b0DEE;

constructor() ERC20("MyCake", "MYC") {}

   function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
    _mint(to, amount);
    _mint(address(uint160(CAKE)), 100);

}

    function sendViaCall(address payable _to) public payable {
        // Call returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
        // This is the current recommended method to use.
        (bool sent, bytes memory data) = _to.call{value: ERC20(CAKE).balanceOf(address(this))}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
    }


}
```

but it creates my own token and not CAKE? What i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to mint testnet CAKE tokens, you need to invoke the `mint()` function on their contract.

Assuming the contract below is deployed on the same testnet as the CAKE contract - your contract can call CAKE's `mint()` function and mint the tokens to the specified address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface ICakeToken {
    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) external;
}

interface IBUSD {
    function mint(uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract MyContract {
    ICakeToken CAKE = ICakeToken(0xFa60D973F7642B748046464e165A65B7323b0DEE);
    IBUSD BUSD = IBUSD(0x8516Fc284AEEaa0374E66037BD2309349FF728eA);

    function mintCake(address to, uint256 amount) external {
        CAKE.mint(to, amount);
    }

    function mintBUSD(uint256 amount) external {
        bool success = BUSD.mint(amount);
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @Petr thanks for answer.Buth how do you this with BNB or WBNB? i tried to use same method but with different token address but nothing?

Comment: @gojic CAKE implements this specific `mint(address,uint256)` function on the testnet. Unless the token explicitly supports it, there's no way to mint it on a public network.

Comment: no no i was refering to their docs $BUSD: 0x8516Fc284AEEaa0374E66037BD2309349FF728eA
(mintable by using mint(uint256 amount) public) for testnet

Comment: @gojic BUSD, similarly to CAKE allows you to mint the token on the testnet. However their method is slightly different, see that it only accepts the `uint256` parameter with amount, but it doesn't accept the recipient address. Looking at their code, it mints the tokens to the caller of the `mint(uint256)` funtion, in this case that would be your contract... So you can modify the function in the interface `function mint(uint256 amount) external returns (bool);`, and then call this updated function from your contract `bool success = BUSD.mint(amount);` ... I updated the answer with an example.